# windows equivalent of this bash command that uses /dev/urandom

Tags: windows, bash, cryptography

Is there a simple Windows equivalent for this bash command:

```
head -c 500 /dev/urandom | tr -dc abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | head -c 9; echo
```

I think the main problem is /dev/urandom, since I've heard of the CryptoAPI, but I don't know if that's cryptographically secure enough.

EDIT: Sorry, the code is used in a php script, and the `%s` represents a string substitution; I forgot to make that substitution when I asked the question. Fixed.

Comment: result: `head: %s: invalid number of bytes`. What do you expect that command to do?

Comment: @Quamis - I updated the original question; sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Keith - I don't want to ask users to install a package like Cygwin just to run a simple PHP script.

Comment: @pythonscript: I wasn't being entirely serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from RFC 4086:

> **7.1.3.  Windows CryptGenRandom**
>
> Microsoft's recommendation to users of the widely deployed Windows
>   operating system is generally to use the CryptGenRandom pseudo-random
>   number generation call with the CryptAPI cryptographic service
>   provider.  This takes a handle to a cryptographic service provider
>   library, a pointer to a buffer by which the caller can provide
>   entropy and into which the generated pseudo-randomness is returned,
>   and an indication of how many octets of randomness are desired.
>
> The Windows CryptAPI cryptographic service provider stores a seed
>   state variable with every user.  When CryptGenRandom is called, this
>   is combined with any randomness provided in the call and with various
>   system and user data such as the process ID, thread ID, system clock,
>   system time, system counter, memory status, free disk clusters, and
>   hashed user environment block.  This data is all fed to SHA-1, and
>   the output is used to seed an RC4 key stream.  That key stream is
>   used to produce the pseudo-random data requested and to update the
>   user's seed state variable.
>
> Users of Windows ".NET" will probably find it easier to use the
>   RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes method interface.

Comment: Thanks for the help; that's more of what I was looking for.